# Canvas with a semi-transparent background

Tags: java, swt

I would like to create a canvas with a semi-transparent background. So I have tried something like this:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Main {

    public static int WIDTH=500;
    public static int HEIGHT=70;
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
        create(shell);


        shell.pack();
        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }


    private static void create(Shell shell){
        Canvas c= new Canvas(shell, SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
        GridData gd= new GridData();
        gd.heightHint=HEIGHT-30;
        gd.widthHint=WIDTH-30;
        c.setLayoutData(gd);
        c.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
        c.setBackground(new Color(shell.getDisplay(), 255, 255, 255, 100));
    }

}
```

But the alpha part of the color (100) I used for the Canvas background doesn't seem to be taken into account by SWT, unless I put 0, if I use 0, the canvas is totally transparent, in all the other cases if opaque.
Did I make some mistake here, or is a SWT problem?

I'm using SWT on Windows 8.

Comment: The code works OK on macOS so this may be a Windows restriction (I can't test on Windows).

Comment: Also make sure you have the latest version of SWT as the color transparency code is quite new and has been updated in newer releases.

Comment: Thank you Greg, which version of STW are you using? I'm on version 4.629

Comment: SWT has about 3 different version numbers(!). I am using the one from the current Eclipse Oxygen.1a release - downloaded from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.7.1a-201710090410/) (SWT only download near the bottom of the page)

Comment: Just tried the same version of you and I got the same problem... :( It seems a problem with Windows implementation then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As greg-449 pointed out this is a bug in SWT for windows environment. I have opened a defect in SWT: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=528249

As a workaround we can always set the aplha on GC painting the canvas by ourself, this approach works in all the environments:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Main {

    public static int WIDTH=500;
    public static int HEIGHT=70;
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
        create(shell);


        shell.pack();
        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }


    private static void create(Shell shell){
        Canvas c= new Canvas(shell, SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
        GridData gd= new GridData();
        gd.heightHint=HEIGHT-30;
        gd.widthHint=WIDTH-30;
        c.setLayoutData(gd);
        c.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TRANSPARENT));
        c.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
        c.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                Rectangle clientArea = c.getClientArea();
                e.gc.setAlpha(100);
                e.gc.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
                e.gc.fillRectangle(clientArea.x,clientArea.y,clientArea.width-1,clientArea.height-1);
            }
        });
    }

}
```